# Ruby on Rails w/Passenger - just trying to get the basics setup...am I missing something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

I'm a rails novice, trying to set it up on a shared hosting site (Dreamhost).  My domain there is configured to use Passenger, with a web root of myrubyapp/public.

Unfortunately, after setting RoR up, all I get is a directory listing of my "public" folder.

Here are the exact steps I took:

- 'rails new myrubapp'
- cd myrubyapp
- rake db:create (just using the basic SQLite get it to work - also tried with MySQL and no change)

At this point, the index.html in 'public' works fine.

- 'rails generate controller home index'
- rm public/index.html
- modify config/routes.rb to uncomment and change the "root :to" line to point to home#index
- touch tmp/restart.txt (which I think is a dreamhostism - it tells Passenger to refresh its cache for this domain)

That's it.  And now I get a directory listing in public instead of rails.

I'm kind of a rails novice, but I've been following the [Getting Started Guide for rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Dreamhost has not been able to give me any clues.  It's entirely possible I'm missing something.  Unfortunately, the myrubyapp/log/production.log is a zero-length empty file (as is everything in myrubyapp/log).  I don't know what the config is for Passenger/Apache, though Dreamhost says other customers are using rails on the same server with no problems.

This is rails 3, btw.

Anyone have a suggestion?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It really sounds like you did not enable RoR on your dreamhost panel properly, are you 100% sure it is enabled? Does the directory listing list the actual files in your project's public folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Passenger does not run. Ask them to check whether it is indeed working for you, or check your control panel to see if it does. If you get a directory listing, it's pretty certain that passenger is not working. Your steps seem fine.

Comment: Yep, Passenger is enabled for this domain.  There's a checkbox for this domain that says "Passenger (Ruby/Python apps only)" and it's checked.  There's nothing else in the panel that is related to Passenger.

The directory listing is the actual files in the project's public folder.

Is there a way to see if Passenger is running properly outside of rails?  i.e., some kind of test I can put in?  

Unfortunately, I'm at the mercy of DH and they say Passenger is working fine on the particular server I'm on and for other people on that server.  I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: It should be working :/ You have setup the production environment right ? It should be the one used with passenger.

Comment: SpyrosP, what I listed is everything I've done.  I believe Passenger always runs in 'production' mode.

Comment: Yes, but what about your environment? Have you set up the production environment properly ? Is your database created ? Passenger does not always run in production, you can specify that. But i'm sure they run production by default.

Comment: I've tried with both MySQL DB and the SQLite config that comes with rails.  So in other words, I've tried both the stock database.yml (which uses SQLite), and a modified database.yml in which the production part is set to use a MySQL DB.  I can connect to the MySQL DB on the command line using the same parameters, so I know the MySQL DB is working.  There didn't seem to be anything more to configure - in Rails 3 I don't think there's that RAILS_ENV in environment.rb setup anymore.

Comment: As a last thing that i can think of, please remove config.ru from your config folder and retry. Sometimes this confuses apache.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two potentially problems right off the bat. First.. In the root :to line, you'll probably want to make sure you capitalize your class properly: 'Home#index' instead of 'home#index'. The other potential problem is that you don't really need to use db:create. db:migrate (for SQLite) will work just fine at most times. Though db:create should be fine too. The latter is more of a stylistic thing than something which is wrong.

As a side note, I used Dreamhost to host a Ruby project of mine for a while. They weren't bad, but the responses were really slow. If your code isn't being hit regularly, they basically 'background' your application and it ends up taking a while for it to spin back up when the next request comes in to it. I ended up with a VPS because of that. YMMV.

Comment: Okay, I double checked on myself (after posting- really shouldn't do that..). It's not actually necessary to uppercase the first letter. Though I have to agree with the others. It seems like there very well may be an RoR not enabled on that particular domain issue.